# Filters login before using website - Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel

same as title, i want to all people when using trang web of me, must be login (look like FB or Twitter, ...) with some of the required as follows:

- If such as the current URL is the '/' (home page), systems display the interfaces registered. (display the rather than the redirect)
- If such as a different URL '/' (home page), systems redirection to login page.

somebody can help me? I'm using laravel framework.

Comment: If you just google `laravel filter`, the first result is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses power thing called filter.

You can use them in any Route::*action* you want.

But a little exemple may helps you.

Following your request :

```
// Check manualy if user is logged. If so, redirect to the dashboard.
// If not, redirect to the login page
Route::get('/', function()
{
   if (Auth::check()) // If user is logged
       return View::make('dashboard')
   return View::make('/login');
}

// Each routes inside this Route::group will check if the user is logged
// Here, /example will only be accessible if you are logged
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth', function()
{
   // All your routes will be here
   Route::get('/example', function()
   {
     return View::make('contents.example');
   }
});
```

Of course, the filter *auth* is built in Laravel. You can find this file in app/filters.php
and modifying it to your needs.
As follow:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('/login'); 
});
```

Comment: If some comment (that_guy) or answer (mine) does ... answer to your question, don't forget to Accept one or another to let people know there is a solution.